# Will Ubuntu 13.10 work with the capacitive touch functions in HP EliteBook Revolve 810?

Tags: 13.10, multi-touch

I have a HP EliteBook Revolve 810 p/n D3K50UT#ABA with 10 finger capacitive touch functions, auto-rotate and many other features. Will Ubuntu 13.10 work with these functions?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04, as well as 13.10 recognise fingertouch.The autorotate function is however not an automatic feature!